# A working checkers/draughts?

Tags: unity, 13.04, games

I am trying to find an implementation of checkers/draughts that works. I did "sudo apt-get install kcheckers" and when I run it I get a window that I can't expand (so it works but just in a small window).  On the terminal I see

```
Your Locale: "en_GB" 
Prefix path: /usr 
Loading Qt translations failed. 
Loading KCheckers translations failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sadly can't seem to change the board size in KCheckers - you can change the board to 'simple-big' in the 'View' menu, but that does not make much difference. It may have last been [updated in 2005](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=14772), so is a real space for development.

You may  want to try [this](http://iloveubuntu.net/checkers-touch-ubuntu-touch-aimed-classic-board-game) - though it is designed for Ubuntu Touch, it is shown working in Ubuntu 13.04 *(with a cursor... so I looks like it works on the Desktop Ubuntu as well.)* - though I get this error when trying to open it:

```
wmobbs@whm2:~$ qmlscene --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/checkers.desktop /usr/share/checkers/checkers.qml
file:///usr/share/checkers/checkers.qml:49 ToolbarActions is not a type
```

I should do a bug report later.

If you are using 13.04, you may want to update it, as 13.04 is now [End Of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) - example instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412186/upgrading-ubuntu-from-13-04-to-13-10/412204#412204).