# Upgrading Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: system-installation

How do I go about installing Ubunbu 13.10?

I have downloaded the distribution already, after acquiring an ebay computer with Ubuntu 13.04 pre-installed. Please can anyone instruct me?

Comment: Have you tried this > [Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 from ISO image](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369838/upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10-from-iso-image)

Comment: @AzkerMohamed - [How To Upgrade Ubuntu From An ISO Image](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image) is a bit better...

Answer (score 1):

The method shown [here](http://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail-to-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander/) should work:

---

First make sure that your data is backed up, and that you have a fast internet connection.

First Update:

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Open 'Software Updater':

[image]

Press 'Upgrade':

[image]
[image]

It should then prompt this - Start the Upgrade...
[image]

...wait a while...

[image]

and reboot.

[image]

If prompted to remove 'obsolete' packages, you can do as you like. Note that with some you may have difficulty installing them, as they may only be available for 13.04 `raring` and not 13.10 `saucy`