# object not found in lampp ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I am a newbie linux user. I have installed x`ampp 1.8.3-2(lampp)` on Ubuntu 13.10 and configured it.

I paste my `www` folder to Ubuntu 13.10 in `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.

Now that the owner of `www` folder is `root`, with create and delete files permission, I changed the permissions with:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/www
```

I can access my old files inside `www` directory, and results in viewing webpage in the browser, with the URL of `localhost/xampp/www/xxx/abc.php`. I can create files like `aaa.php` inside `www` but when I am trying view `aaa.php` file its says

```
 Object not found

 The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.`

 Error 404
```

`localhost Apache/2.4.7 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3` 
Cannot execute new files, and I cannot execute modified code. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. You might be root, but Apache runs "as" the `www-data` user.

Comment: i am running as a user. if you are suggesting like to change owner of www folder from root to user, i have even tried that sudo chmod username /opt/lamp/htdocs/www. but no success.

Comment: Could be you didn't properly configured Apache... Anyway this isn't about Ubuntu. Try superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: the httpd.conf that is found in path /etc/httpd.conf is not found in ubuntu 13.10 maybe.even tried something about virtualhost from a forum. ok thnkx nyway will surely visit there

Comment: "sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/www" no you did not. You did "sudo chmod 775 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/www". "Object not found" your webserver's root path is not correct. Check the apache log file (/var/log/apache/access* and error*). It will tell you why the error occurs.

Comment: i did chmod 777 but how to chng the php file owner from me to root as i see other existing files that are running have root ownership of the .php files. the folder created has root owner but not the files. how to do that

Comment: @Rinzwind the location /var/log/apache not found.

Comment: @black no 777, security wise bad ;) and 2nd: try /var/log/apache2/ There must be 2 log files that will explain it all.

Comment: Did you upgrade to 13.10?

Comment: yeah m using `13.10`and its solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path i was using was wrong.i was using `/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/a.php` rather it should be `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/a.php` that is why its cant be found. as i have url that responds in `http://localhost/xampp/www` so i had to just put my directories and files inside `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www` and it works fine.thnkx all

Comment: Note that 13.04 is now End-Of-Life - support for 13.04 [ended last month](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Update it to 13.10, or even 12.04, while you still can. If you have problems, [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/412186/upgrading-ubuntu-from-13-04-to-13-10) or [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) may be of help.

Comment: @wilf as i have mentioned it `ubuntu 13.10` what i am currently using is upgraded from 13.04 to `ubuntu 13.10 saucysalamander`.

Comment: yeah by mistake i wrote `13.04` inside the body,but the title was `13.10`

Comment: Quite alot of the flags for closing the questions *(a total of 5 flags are needed to close a question)* were about this being about an EOL release... I have flagged for it to be reopened.